# how to add my domain name in ssl after lock icon like twitter.com

Tags: php, ssl, web

I have created a website and connect ssl license, and now  I want  to  change lock  icon  and  add there  name of my company  like twitter.com (Twitter,inc), help me  please  how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the privilege of buying an [*EV certificate*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EV_certificate).
Yes, they're quite expensive.

Comment: I had to buy it with ssl license, and pay separately for it ?